# Error on unit tests using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

Trying to run my unit tests but i have been getting one error over and over again and I have no idea what causes it. Could you please help? The error is as follows:

```
Error: write EPIPE     
at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)     
at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:611:20)     
at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:507:12)     
at sendHelper (cluster.js:722:8)     
at send (cluster.js:681:5)
```

Comment: Show the code of failing test.

Comment: exactly code first

Comment: hi,the code is long i'm gonna send it piece by piece i have no idea if you can be able to understand

Comment: describe("put user", function () {
    before(function (done) {
        mockData.RoleID = chance.integer()
        mockData.UserName = chance.string({length: 100})
        sinon
            .stub(user, "insert")
            .yieldsAsync({inserted: true, newId: chance.integer()});

        sinon
            .stub(config, "get");

        sinon
            .stub(connection, "getDbInstance");

        done();
    });
    after(function (done) {
        user.insert.restore();
        config.get.restore();
        connection.getDbInstance.restore();
        done();
    });

Comment: it('should put 200 user successfully', function (done) {
        request(server.baseURL)
            .put('/api/v1/user')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .send(mockData)
            .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                /* istanbul ignore if */
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

Comment: if (err)
                    return done(err);
                expect(res.body).to.not.be.null;
                expect(res.body).to.not.be.undefined;
                expect(res.body).to.be.an('Object');
                expect(res.body).to.have.property("inserted");
                expect(res.body.inserted).to.not.be.null;
                expect(res.body.inserted).to.not.be.undefined;
                expect(res.body.inserted).to.be.equal(true);

Comment: expect(res.body).to.have.property("newId");
                expect(res.body.newId).to.not.be.null;
                expect(res.body.newId).to.not.be.undefined;
                expect(res.body.newId).to.be.above(0);
                expect(user.insert).to.have.been.calledOnce;
                return done();

Comment: Above listings are unreadable. I doubt anybody will decrypt them for you. To increase probability of helpful answer, edit your question with proper formatted code.

Comment: This is my server file